# Compare taxes Cobb-Douglass and more

Tags: microeconomics, utility, taxation, cobb-douglas

Let a utility function for a consumer be defined as $u(x_{1},x_{2})=x_{1}^{1/2} x_{2}^{1/2}$. With the budget $x_{1}p_{1}+x_{2}p_{2}=m$. With values $p_1=p_2=1, m=32$. The state now adds a tax of unit 3 on $p_{1}$ (pr. Unit $x_1$)

How does it effect utility? What does the state earn?

- I got the utility before to be 16 and after to be 8 with taxes correlating to 12 pr unit $x_1$

**The state now considers an income tax such that the income is now $m-T$ How much will the state earn with the new system *whilst keeping the consumer indifferent*? Which system is better?**

- I figured that i solve for the Tax in the utility function under optimal demand conditions so that i kepy utility equal to 8. This gave me 16 units of income tax.

How does one do the last part mathematically. I figure the income tax is better for the consumer but how can i show it mathematically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intuition you have is correct. Mathematically you can show it by first deriving the optimal choices with the lump sum income tax. So you will set up the following lagrangian:

$$\mathcal{L} = x^{1/2}_1 x^{1/2}_2 - \lambda [x_1p_1+x_2p_2 - m + T] $$

This gives you 3 FOC's the budget constraint and:

$$ 0.5x_1^{-0.5} x_2^{0.5} = \lambda p_1 \\
0.5x_2^{-0.5} x_2^{0.5} = \lambda p_2$$

Solve for optimal $x_1^*$ and $x_2^*$:

$$ x_1^* =  \frac{m-T}{2p_1} = \frac{32-T}{2} \\
x_2^* =  \frac{m-T}{2p_2} = \frac{32-T}{2}$$

Where here the second equalities take advantage of the assumptions that $p_1 = p_2=1$ and $m=32$.

Now  you can just plug this into the utility function and assuming you made no mistake equate this to the utility with the consumption tax on $p_1$ so you will have:

$$ 8 =  \left( \frac{32-T}{2}\right)^{0.5} \left( \frac{32-T}{2}\right)^{0.5} \\
T =16$$

So under the income tax regime government gets $T=16> t=12$ while consumer still has the same utility as under the consumption tax, meaning the income tax is better. The intuition for that is that income tax does not distort the relative prices only has an income effect whereas consumption tax has both income and substitution effects.

Comment: I have done everything up to " The intuition for that is that income tax does not distort the relative prices only has an income effect whereas consumption tax has both income and substitution effects." Can this quantity actually be shown I get the reasons but no idea on how to show it for this example?

Comment: @bymathformath what do you mean by quantity? The substitution effect will be there with consumption tax because it disturbs the relative prices. With consumption price of 3 for $x_1$ the price of $x_1$ increases from $1$ to $4$ making the consumer want to substitute away from consuming $x_1$ to consuming $x_2$ in addition to consumer having lower income due to tax (as it changes the budget constraint from $x_1+x_2=32$ to $4x_1+x_2 =32$. Income tax only lowers the income without distorting the prices. You can quantify these effects using hicksian decomposition - but that was not part of the Q

Comment: "You can quantify these effects using hicksian decomposition" I was lacking the words to describe it, sorry. But yes - this. That is what I meant*

Comment: How would one do that with this Cobb-Douglas?

Comment: @bymathformath with hicksian decomposition, you can calculate the substitution effect by looking at what is the change in demand, holding utility constant and then the income effect will be rest. However, note this was not part of the question in the black so you should not just add that to an answer unless requested I was just giving you little bit of an tidbit of intuition how come that we got the result that we got. It is trivial to see that in the case of income tax there will be no substitution effect as that requires changes in prices.

Comment: it is requested but I have no clue on how to approach it mathematically. Have been starring at it for hours upon hours, unfortunately..

Comment: @bymathformath for substitution effect you would calculate difference between hicksian demand when price is $4$ and $1$. Hicksian  demand is demand at some constant utility. You would do that by plugging result that you get by dividing the FOCs into utility (e.g. plug $x_2 = p_1/p_2x_1$ into U in your case and solve for $x_1$. In your case hicksian demand function will be $U \sqrt{\frac{p_2}{p_1} }=x_1$ . For substitution effect you want to keep $U$ constant at the original level 16 so you will simply calculate difference using new

Comment: prices so substitution effect will be $16 \sqrt{1/4} - 16 \sqrt{1/1} = -8$. The income effect will be just the total difference between consumption of $x_1$ in the two scenario minus the substitution effect. You can do the same for good $x_2$. In the income case scenario there is only income effect so all difference between $x_1$ and $x_2$ between and after tax are just income effects

Comment: Hello, I tried to calculate it here https://ibb.co/pwbSXKJ. First calculations are for income tax where the total seems to be -8. The next ones are for unit tax corresponding to -1. Something is obviously wrong but i dont know where.

Comment: @bymathformath 1. When you are calculating $\partial h / \partial p$ you are using incorrect demand you need hicksian demand as explained in my previous comments. 2. This is for infentisimal changes - you are changing price from 1 to 4 for that you need to follow the method outlined above where you calculate difference between the two hicksian demands

Comment: I just can not seem to do it this way.

Comment: https://ibb.co/gTDRVpz with these calculations i get -8 for income and -1 for unit tax.

Comment: @bymathformath as mentioned before you should calculate the change in compensated demands for substitution effect.

Comment: oh so only compare substitution effect for both cases? the one where the income is 32 but with a tax of 3 pr unit on good 1 and the other case where the income is now 16?

Comment: @bymathformath you can compare both but income effect is just total total effect - substitution effect. Total effect can be easily calculated that is just x_1 and x_2 after taxes - x_1 and x_2 before taxes. So for example if after tax x_1 is let’s say 2 and x_2 is let’s say 3 and before tax they were both 5 you would get total effect for x_1 is -3 and total effect for x_2 is -2. Then for income effect you just subtract the substitution effect (explained in previous comments) from the total effect. Also in income tax scenario substitution effect should be zero (use that to double check results)

Comment: I give up on it. I can not make it to make sense with slutsky equation.

Comment: @bymathformath why do you stubbornly insist on using slutsky equation instead of following the steps I recommend above. I even derived the compensated demand for you so you don’t need to do anything else just plug in numbers

Comment: Because that is what I am asked to do.

Comment: @bymathformath are you asked to specifically use slutsky equation or just to calculate substitution and income effect?

Comment: Told to use Slutsky to show why the one tax is more desirable for the consumer than the other. I get these results now https://ibb.co/82DX7HW but then i get stuck

Comment: *I get stuck because - for me - I can not conclude anything from this?

Comment: @bymathformath but slutsky cannot be used to show one tax is more desirable than another. It can only quantify the amount of income and substitution effect but for tax desirability it is the total effect what matters - and for total effect you don’t need slutsky - so either you are omitting some important parts of the request or it does not make any sense whatsoever. Also for slutsky equation you still need to use to compensated demand shown above for substitution effect.

Comment: but total effect is just sub+inc=total right? Wouldn't you then with this information be able to show that one of them is more desirable?

Comment: @bymathformath no it wouldn’t because for utility and government revenue only thing that matters is the total effect on consumption - also then for checking desirability of the tax by for example checking if government can get greater revenue while keeping utility constant -as already shown in the answer. Separating it into substitution and income effect does not tell you anything about the desirability of the tax itself, that only tells you what causes the total effect but what causes the total effect has nothing to do whatsoever with which tax is better

Comment: Okay I see. So another approach is actually required to find desirability of one tax over another...

Comment: @bymathformath well already in my answer it is shown that income tax is more desirable- the substitution and income part was just a loose intuition why - if one tax has only income effects then there are less ways how it can disrupt people’s optimal choices - so that is the intuition but for the tax desirability itself it does not matter what is the substitution and income effect. If income tax would happen to have such a great income effect that consumption tax with both income and substitution effect would have smaller total effect income tax would be worse. But save for special cases

Comment: The sort of lump sum income tax like in your problem has less channels to disrupt optimal behavior so it makes sense that you will find that it’s total effect will generally be lower. But again that is just an economic intuition the proof that one tax is better than other one is already in answer to your Q

Comment: I guess I missunderstood the way to interpret effect. But where is the answer in a mathematical frame that shows why? Would I need to draw a figure of it? Because I get the argument but not the maths behind it.

Comment: @bymathformath the answer above shows that *holding consumer utility constant at*: $U=8$ government can get 16 units of tax with income tax, and in your original question you said that with consumption tax the government revenue was 12 (i did not double checked that I assumed your original calculation was accurate). Since 16>12 and consumer has the same utility income tax must be better since consumer is equally well off and government has more tax revenue. I dont understand why that is not clear.

Comment: Got the revenue from $R=x_{1}^{*}(p_{1}'-p_{1})= \frac{32}{2 \cdot (3+1)}((3+1)-1)=12$. But now I get it. "Since 16>12 and consumer has the same utility income tax must be better since consumer is equally well off and government has more tax revenue." - The assignment was just explained in a strange way that led to confusion.

Comment: @bymathformath ok glad that we resolved it. Sorry if that last paragraph confused you I just wanted to give you also some economic intuition for the result. Also if you think the answer above solved your issue consider accepting it - it helps to improve our economics beta site statistics

Comment: All good! WIll do. BTW, the revenue is correct i suppose, right? Got anxiety of all of this work so far.

Comment: @bymathformath yes the revenue seems to be correct